# Python Package that can Navigate File Dialogs for Mac OS

Tags: python, web-browser

I need a Python Package that:

- can handle file dialog windows so that if I have one open using selenium, I can upload a file.
- doesn't do anything physical, such as moving a mouse or simulating keypresses.

PyAutoIt seems like it should work, but the problem is that it isn't available for mac OS. What alternatives are there?

Comment: Please rewrite the question title after reading  [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) thanks!